# Having problems with my drill down in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have two reports: **Summary** and **Detail**. They are both located in the same directory and I am trying to do this stuff in iReport 5.0.1. I am trying to make a field in my **Summary** report so that I can click on it and it will run and show the **Detail** report. The field is: **$F{reason_id}**.

In the Summary report I created a hyperlink in one of my fields like so:

**Hyperlink target:** *Self*

**Hyperlink type:** *ReportExecution*

In my Link parameters I have the parameters:

**_report:** *detail*

**reason_id:** $F{reason_id}

**start_date:** $P{start_date}

**end_date:** $P{end_date}

When I click **Preview** in my **Summary** report, I enter all my parameters, then I get this error:

```
Error filling print... Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : detail
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : detail 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillHyperlinkHelper.evaluateHyperlinkParameters(JRFillHyperlinkHelper.java:82) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:504) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:431) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:459) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745) 
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891) 
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nrt_detail for class: Sample_1362063546538_723686 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:86) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239) 
    at Sample_1362063546538_723686.evaluate(calculator_Sample_1362063546538_723686:229) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190) 
    ... 20 more 
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Edit:

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" hyperlinkType="ReportExecution">
            <reportElement uuid="39530e77-e079-4f4b-9533-a8f7c1a1b17d" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box leftPadding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reason_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkParameter name="_report">
                <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA["C:/JasperReports/detail"]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
            </hyperlinkParameter>
            <hyperlinkParameter name="reason_id">
                <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{reason_id}]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
            </hyperlinkParameter>
            <hyperlinkParameter name="start_date">
                <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{start_date}]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
            </hyperlinkParameter>
            <hyperlinkParameter name="end_date">
                <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{end_date}]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
            </hyperlinkParameter>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your report expression to the full path, such as "/reports/folder/detail" and make sure you include the quotation marks around the report name!

Comment: So I changed it to `"C:/JasperReports/detail"`. The report runs now, but when I click on the link, nothing happens.

Comment: Does the subreport run on its own? Do you have the asterisks around your parameters in the expression field? Try removing them.

Comment: Yes, the subreport runs on its own. The asterisks are from me trying to italicize those words in my post. I don't know why the words weren't in italics.

Comment: An FYI for later -- when you push this report to JasperReports Server, make sure you change the C:\... path to the new path in JasperReports Server.

Comment: Ok thanks. I added the jrxml code in an edit to the original post.

Comment: That looks OK. Can we see the JRXML for the destination report as well?

Comment: With the query and everything? or just the part with the parameters?